# How to prevent nuget from reverting to older versions of dependent packages when updating a package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

When updating a nuget package to a new version, dependencies of the package being updated are removed and reinstated as the lowest allowable version of those dependent packages. The package manager console output is as follows:

`Update-Package web.CMS -version 6.5.0-develop-140728152`

`Updating 'Web.CMS' from version '6.5.0-Trunk-1406031714' to '6.5.0-develop-1407281525' in project 'App.Cms'.`

`Remove 'Web.CMS 6.5.0-Trunk-1406031714' from project App.Cms.`

`Remove 'Cms.Assemblies 6.1.379' from project App.Cms.`

`Remove 'Web 7.3.0' from project App.Cms.`

`Remove 'Core 8.0.0-Trunk-1406251804' from project App.Cms.`

`Add 'Core 6.1.0' to project App.Cms.`

`Add 'Web 6.0.0' to project App.Cms.`

`Add 'Cms.Assemblies 6.0.530' to project App.Cms.`

`Add 'Web.CMS 6.5.0-develop-1407281525' to project App.Cms.`

The dependencies section of the Web.CMS package nuspec file is as follows, as you can see the dependent package versions are those that have been installed as part of the package update.

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency id="Core" version="6.1" />
   <dependency id="Web" version="6.0" />
   <dependency id="Cms.Assemblies" version="[6.0.530,7)"/>
</dependencies>
```

Is there a way to update a package without the dependent packages reverting to older versions, as happens here? We can do it by uninstalling the package and installing the new version, that's for from ideal however as some packages are used by several projects in a solution and it has to be done for each project individually.

Comment: I would try a few combinations of the `-IgnoreDependencies` and the `-IncludePrerelease` options for Update-Package to see what affect that has.

Comment: Update NuGet. This behavior was fixed in a recent version.

Comment: I am using the latest version, 2.8.5. My understanding is that this reversion to the oldest version was introduced in v2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by including the -IgnoreDependencies switch:

`Update-Package web.CMS -version 6.5.0-develop-140728152 -IgnoreDependencies`